# What kind of word is HOW here? ---> "We will look at how this is used"

Tags: word-usage, grammar, subordinate-clauses

Sentence: We will look at ***how*** this is used.
My question is here,
1. Is  a word "***how***" subordinator in this sentence? If not, then what is it?
2. **We will look at** and **this is used**, are these two independent clauses?
3. Are these independent clauses connected by a word "how"?

Comment: Nice question +1. Welcome to ELL :)

Answer (score 2):

### **Short answer**

> We will look at how this is used.

This sentence contains a subordinate clause

- how it was used

This is in fact an interrogative clause. And the word *how* here is an interrogative adverb.

---

### **Full answer:**

**Adjuncts**

We often put extra information at the end of a clause explaining when, where,why or how something happened. These phrases that give us this extra information are *Adjuncts*. We call phrases that give us extra information about the way that something was done or the way that something happened *manner adjuncts*. Here are some examples:

- The elephants danced *beautifully*.
- They ate the donuts *in a hurry*.
- They did it *like this.*

**Open Interrogative clauses**

Open interrogative clauses have a *wh-* word at the beginning. They also have a gap in the rest of the clause which tells us what the *wh-* word refers to. Look at the following sentence:

- He punched him.

If we make an interrogative clause with this sentence, we need a gap for the clause to make sense:

- Tell me who [he punched him].

The interrogative clause above does not make sense because we do not know who the *who-* refers to. After we put in the gap, it becomes clear:

- Tell me who [ ___ punched him]
- Tell me who [ he punched ____ ]

We understand *who* in these sentences as having the same meaning as the missing part of the clause. So we could model those clauses like this:

- Tell me who <sub>(i)</sub> [ ____<sub>(i)</sub> punched him]
- Tell me who<sub>(i)</sub> [he punched ____<sub>(i)</sub>]

When we want to ask about the manner in which something is done, we can use an interrogative clause with *how*. When we do this there will be a gap at the end of the clause where the manner adjunct would be:

- They used it like this
- Tell me how [they used it <s>like this</s>]
- Tell me how<sub>(i)</sub> [they used it ____<sub>(i)</sub>]

**The Original Poster's question**

> > We will look at how<sub>(i)</sub> [this is used _____<sub>(i)</sub> ].

In the sentence above, the word *how* is an interrogative word corresponding to the gap in the end of the interrogative clause where the Adjunct would normally be. Because we associate Adjuncts with adverbs, most grammars would regard *how* as an interrogative adverb here.

There are indeed sentences which use *how* as a subordinator. But in such sentences there is no gap in the clause after *how*. The subordinator *how* can always be replaced by the word *that*:

- I went to see my Dad and told him how I'd failed my exams and had to drop out of college.

The sentence above probably does not mean that I explained the manner in which I'd failed my exams and dropped out of college, but just the fact that I had. We can easily replace the word *how* with the word *that* here:

- I went to see my Dad and told him that I'd failed my exams and had to drop out of college.

Notice that if we try to do that with the Original Poster's example, it becomes ungrammatical:

- *We will look at that this is used. (ungrammatical)

This shows that the word *how* is not a subordinator in the Original Poster's sentence.

Comment: Just so I can understand your use of the jargon, are you reserving *subordinator* for words that mark subordination only when they play no role within the subordinate clause?  And if so, do you have a term for words that mark subordination in general?  Say, something that covers both this "interrogative" *how* and the relative *that*?

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan So, I'm using a *CamGEL* or *OMEG* grammar where *subordinator* is a word class like *verb* or *preposition*. So *how* there can't be a subordinator because it's an adverb. I don't have a word for *subordinator* in the sense of any word that happens to appear as part of/before a subordinate clause, but that doesn't mean there isn't one in those grammars. I'd point out though that interrogative *how* here shouldn't really be thought of as a word that comes at the beginning of a subordinate clause. It could occur at the end: :"You did that *how*?", for example.

Comment: Gotcha.  I put "interrogative" in quotes because, although interrogative in "how is this used?" or "this is used how?", there's no question in "how this is used".  That clause has a meaning that can be an answer but not a question.  I see it as similar to the referent shared by "what we talk about" and "the things we discuss", where my trouble labeling either of those as interrogative might be more obvious.  I don't find myself objecting to, say, *subordinating adverb* and *subordinating pronoun*.  But, yeah, *subordinator* as a part of speech shouldn't include *subordinating adverb*.  Thanks.